# How do I eliminate the effect of one variable while doing local regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning

I have a time series of data, each corresponds to a time point, a dose and an expression level. Say the dose is increasing in a trend like 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 40. Now I want to do the local regression with time based on the data, the problem is, how can I cancel the dose effect?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by local regression you mean some type of smoother, you can use a Generalized Additive Model.